# Selenium PhantomJS doesn't exit when stopping java execution in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, phantomjs

I am using selenium and phantomJS to do some scraping, when the program finishes by itself all the `phantomjs.exe` processes finish, how ever if I was to launch the program and then stop the execution in eclipse the `phantomjs.exe` processes survive. This can become quite annoying as I end up having to end them all manually in task manager.

An example program which exhibits this is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver[] drivers = new WebDriver[5];

        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < drivers.length; i++){
                drivers[i] = new PhantomJSDriver();
            }

            System.out.println("End the program now"); 
            drivers[0].get("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
        } finally {
            for (int i = 0; i < drivers.length; i++){
                WebDriver driver = drivers[i];
                driver.close();
                driver.quit();
                driver = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get it so that if execution stops it ends all the processes?

Comment: Use webdriver connect feature.

Comment: @nikpon could you go into a bit more detail/provide an example?